# Laravel 5 how to include config file?

Tags: laravel-5, php-7.2

I am using Laravel 5.5 and I have a config file in dir `app\Json\Schemas\TestSchema.php` which contains an array with configurations like this:

```
return [
  'value' => 'string'
];
```

What is the best way to include file dynamically?

In my model

```
namespace App;

use App\Json\Traits\JsonModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{ 
    public function getJsonSchema($schema)
    {
        return  'App\\Json\\Schemas\\'.$schema; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to move your config file to the `config` folder. Lets assume you call it `schema.php`.

You can load the config file in your code using (where `schema` is the name of the config file without the `.php`):

```
config('schema');
```

And if you want the `value`, you can use dot notation (where `schema` is the name of the config file, and `value` is a key in the config array):

```
$value = config('schema.value');
```

Therefore the `getJsonSchema` function can be updated to (where `$schema` is the name of the config file):

```
public function getJsonSchema($schema)
{
    return  'App\\Json\\Schemas\\'.config($schema.'.value'); 
}
```